# Process API response

Tags: c#, curl, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to make an API request using C# HttpClient class.

I managed to get an OK response from the API request, but now I want to process that response content to get the user info.

This is my code:

```
 private async void GetRefreshToken()
    {
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), "https://www.strava.com/oauth/token"))
            {
                var multipartContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
                multipartContent.Add(new StringContent(CONSTANTS.CLIENT_ID), "client_id");
                multipartContent.Add(new StringContent(CONSTANTS.CLIENT_SECRET), "client_secret");
                multipartContent.Add(new StringContent(userCtrl.StravaAuthToken), "code");
                multipartContent.Add(new StringContent(""), "grant_type");
                request.Content = multipartContent;

                var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);                   
            }
        }
    }
```

The response variable parsed to string returns this:

```
StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  Connection: keep-alive
  X-Download-Options: noopen
  Status: 200 OK
  X-Request-Id: d9fc7423-4d6b-2342-9d3a-614fd583e008
  Referrer-Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
  X-FRAME-OPTIONS: DENY
  X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
  X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies: none
  Vary: Origin
  X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
  Cache-Control: must-revalidate, max-age=0, private
  Date: Mon, 13 Apr 2020 11:08:57 GMT
  ETag: W/"01b8306a9b65e970f36bacbec682342f9"
  Via: 1.1 linkerd
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
}
```

But as I checked with Postman, the content from the API response should look like this. I want to obtain the refresh & access tokens:

```
{
"token_type": "Bearer",
"expires_at": 1586793993,
"expires_in": 18150,
"refresh_token": "a6a5s7d5as8dasdad75a7d5757a5d7asd67576ae",
"access_token": "a9sdas87da9s8d7asd9a7s9d7as9d7as7d97asd7",
"athlete": {
    "id": 878960,
    "username": "username",
    "resource_state": 2,
    "firstname": "Name",
    "lastname": "Lastname",
    "city": null,
    "state": null,
    "country": null,
    "sex": "M",
    "premium": false,
    "summit": false,
    "created_at": "2019-08-01T14:53:11Z",
    "updated_at": "2019-08-01T14:54:00Z",
    "badge_type_id": 0,
    "profile_medium": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14dfgdfg233WZ_rdRmLMbLnqKKoytbxH-UBm",
    "profile": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GhrEsdfgs3WZ_rdRmLMbLnqKKoytbxH-UBm",
    "friend": null,
    "follower": null
    }
}
```

I think that with my code, I'm only obtaining the status from the API request, but not it's content. If so, how can I obtain the content from the API request and parse it to JSON format?

Thanks, I'm 100% new to the API world, so please make simple explanations :D

Answer (score 2):

To get the json string use `await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()`. You can then parse it as a json string and find the token ([Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) can help).